# 3D canvas guided tour

Tags: javascript, 3d, setinterval

I would like to create a JavaScript function that invokes the following function on all positions declared, one after another, waiting few seconds between each movement.

```js
function actionsToolbar(action) {
else if(action=='tour' || action=='tour_on') { 
       presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.179, 0.291, 4.6983, 13.865, 1.28]);
  presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.179, 0.291, 13.178, 22.002, 1.28]);
  presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.179, 0.291, 32.086, 26.127, 1.28]);
  presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.123, 0.197, 33.346, 26.241, 1.28]);
  presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.018, -0.0766, 33.346, 26.24, 1.28]);
  presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.018, -0.0766, -8.823, 29.99, 1.25]);

                                   }
   }
```

Comment: Mention what error you are getting

Comment: Only the first function is being enabled, the camera doesn't move to the other positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

```js
 else if(action=='tour' || action=='tour_on') { 
     loop(
         function() { presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.179, 0.291, 4.6983, 13.865, 1.28]); }, 
         function() { presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.179, 0.291, 13.178, 22.002, 1.28]); },
         function() { presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.179, 0.291, 32.086, 26.127, 1.28]); },
         function() { presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.123, 0.197, 33.346, 26.241, 1.28]); },
         function() { presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.018, -0.0766, 33.346, 26.24, 1.28]); },
         function() { presenter.animateToTrackballPosition([0.018, -0.0766, -8.823, 29.99, 1.25]); }
   );
    
     }
   }

   function loop() {
    var args = arguments;
    if (args.length <= 0)
        return;
    (function chain(i) {
        if (i >= args.length || typeof args[i] !== 'function')
            return;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            args[i]();
            chain(i + 1);
        }, 2000);
    })(0);
}
```